# Multiply a fraction

Tags: fractions

It is necessary to multiply the fraction in accordance with the figure.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\begin{document}
$$ \frac{4a + 8b}{2 + 6c} = \frac{(4a + 8b) \cdot (2 - 6c)}{(2 + 6c) \cdot (2-6c)}  $$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what's your issue exactly? PS: You don't need `\inputenc` with a current LaTeX setup. PPS: I have added the output of your MWE to your posting.

Comment: The problem is to write the multiplier on top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this? (Adjust the height of the "special superscript" term via the first argument of `\raisebox`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[english]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathrlap macro

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{4a + 8b\mathrlap{\raisebox{2.2ex}{$\backslash(2-6c)$}}}{2 + 6c} 
\hphantom{\backslash(2-6c)}
= \frac{(4a + 8b) \cdot (2-6c)}{(2 + 6c) \cdot (2-6c)}
\]
\end{document}
```